# YouTube HTML5 player crop/stretch

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way of cropping youtube videos directly with youtube API via parameters?

I would like to achieve something like:

- http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146402

Some of the videos are having quite big borders and I would prefer to get rid of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not something that you as an embedder can do. If you're just playing back videos embedded on your site, you can use whatever size player you'd like (as long as it's larger than the minimum allowed size), but the player will automatically insert horizontal or vertical black bars if you use a player aspect ratio that differs from the source video's. You can't explicitly "crop" a video in an embed.